# View state and transient

Tags: visualforce

This is for academic purposes

I am trying to run some code from visualforce in practise and came across this sample page and related controller

page is

```
<apex:page controller=”myController” >
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title=”My Content” mode=”edit”>
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton action=”{!save}” value=”Save”/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlockSection title=”My Content Section”
columns=”2”>
<apex:outputLabel for=”aName”>Account Name:</
apex:outputLabel>
<apex:inputText value=”{!accountName}”/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller code is

```
public with sharing class myController {
private final Id accountId&nbsp;;
transient public final String accountName {get; set; }
public myController() {
Account account = [select Id, Name from Account where id
=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(‘id’)];
accountId = account.Id&nbsp;;
accountName = account.Name&nbsp;;
}
public PageReference save() {
Account myAccount = [select name from Account where id
=:accountId];
myAccount.name = accountName;
update myAccount;
return null;
}
}
```

where i am confused is,

```
myAccount.name = accountName;
```

This code works like this:

Page gets pre populated with account name on load.User enters edits account name.Clicks Save.It gets saved to DB.

Now this is where i am confused:

We marked 'account name' variable as transient in controller.So how come value entered by 
user  still persist in 'accountname' variable.
When user clicks save,save method is executed during the post back request.since accountname is not view state i thought variable will not have the value entered by user

Maybe i don't understand view state properly. Can somebody clarify this please?

Comment: I think Save method is executed in the same context or ??

Comment: as per post back execution order--action method is triggered separately?https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_postback_request.htm

Comment: I think the save method is the action which triggered the post back right ? So viewstate is updated right after the method

Comment: My confusion was how come save method at that point has the  value entered by user.As its not in view state

Comment: well it's not in view state but it is in the same context so it's visible :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Transient variables are not stored in the view state, but can be regenerated by the post back if bound to an input element. In general, you only need to use the view state for elements not bound to an input element and need to maintain state between post backs. The standard controller for a page, for example, should not be transient, because it won't stick. However, any element bound by input elements don't need to be saved in the view state if they are rendered.

In other words, the view state is first restored into memory (deserialized), and since accountName wasn't stored in the view state (it is transient), the initial value is null. Then, Visualforce calls set(accountName, value), because it's bound to a rendered input element, which effectively restores its state. Finally, save() is called and the value is correctly populated.

Comment: that was really helpful and new information..thanks :)(I did try with a transient output element and could see in DEBUG log value is not getting stored between states :))..thanks again

Comment: Just one more confusion on this.can you please explain.assume account name was not transient and example above is same.Initially name was 'AccountA' and i changed to 'AccountB'.This statement->'In other words, the view state is first restored into memory (deserialized), and since accountName wasn't stored in the view state (it is transient), the initial value is null.' will accountname has 'AccountA' or 'AccountB' at this point. I am struggling to figure out where exactly is user entered data is getting stored(and when),as updating view state step comes only towards end in execution order

Comment: If it were not transient, it would have the value 'AccountA' until the setter were called, in which case 'AccountA' would be overwritten with 'AccountB'. If you were using a custom setter method, you could prove this: `public string accountName { get; set { system.debug(accountName); accountName = value; } }`.

Comment: so if ie the case--where exactly does the data 'AccountB' entered by user is stored(if not in view state.) when user enters it .How i understood is. 1.page is displayed on browser(view state created) 2. user edits account click save 3.viewstate gets updated 4and setters when it gets executed refers to this updated view state.where am i going wrong :(

Comment: can you please point me to right link/explain regarding this..

Comment: I don't have a link, but... It's stored in the form's parameters. There is no direct access to this area of memory, as it is managed by the Visualforce runtime engine. The "setter" stage of the Visualforce engine is when this value becomes assigned to the controller's memory (the heap) from the form parameters. Once it is part of the heap, it remains there for the rest of the transaction, unless you change the value. Once the Visualforce engine reaches the "getter" state, the value is re-encoded back into a form parameter via an input field.

Comment: The value is not serialized into the view state when it is transient.

Comment: it all makes sense now .really kind of you to explain in detail..There is only one thing i have left with ..i noticed in devmode footer view state tab-->say for eg:.if there is a non transient variable who has get;set; parameter(or a get only var) whose set method is not called during say initial page load(means value is null for that variable)..In view state tab,this variable is not shown-is it because value is null? or its never in view state until setter is called and as you explained initially 'effectively restores its state'

Comment: can you please confirm this one last point

Comment: Yes, if a variable isn't set at all, it usually won't appear in the view state until it is set. It's usually better to explicitly initialize any variables in the constructor so they will appear in the view state. Of course, transient variables should never appear in the view state.

Comment: ok..that means,,its(non transient ones which are not set) always there..but don't 'appear',,Many thanks :)