# Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded

Tags: visualforce

How can I avoid this error? I read similar post without getting any working solutions for me. When I try to upload file larger than about 150k, I get the error.

```
 <apex:page controller="FormCurriculumController" showHeader="false">

<script>

 function show() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="block";

}

</script>



<style type="text/css">
body { background-color:#FFF; }
.erroreMsg, .required { color:#F00; }
</style>

<apex:form styleClass="wwwtesto" rendered="{!NOT(saved)}">
    <p>Fields marked with an * are mandatory.</p>
    <apex:messages styleClass="required" />
    <br/>
    <p>
        <apex:outputLabel value="First name *" for="firstName"/>
        <apex:inputField id="firstName" required="true" value="{!curriculum.FirstName__c}"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <apex:outputLabel value="Last name *" for="lastName"/>
        <apex:inputField id="lastName" required="true" value="{!curriculum.LastName__c}"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <apex:outputLabel value="Email *" for="email"/>
        <apex:inputField id="email" required="true" value="{!curriculum.Email__c}"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <apex:outputLabel value="Message" for="note"/>
        <apex:inputField id="note" required="false" value="{!curriculum.Note__c}"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <apex:outputLabel value="Attachment" for="resume"/>
        <apex:inputFile id="resume" fileName="{!fileName}" contentType="{!contentType}" value="{!resume}" size="45"/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <apex:inputCheckbox id="privacy" required="true" value="{!privacy}"/>I authorise the use of my personal data in compliance with Legislative Decree 196/03.
    </p>
    <p><apex:commandButton value="Send" action="{!save}" onclick="show()"/></p> 
    <div id="myDiv" style="display:none;"><apex:image value="{!$Resource.Loader}"/></div>
  </apex:form>
  <apex:outputText styleClass="wwwtesto" rendered="{!saved}" value="Thank you for submitting your resume."/>

</apex:page>
```

CLASS:

```
public class FormCurriculumController { 
public Curriculum__c curriculum {get; set;}
public Boolean privacy {get; set;}
public Boolean saved {get; set;}
public String styleClass {get; set;}
// Allegato
public Blob resume {get; set;}
public String contentType {get; set;}
public String fileName {get; set;}


public FormCurriculumController () {
    curriculum = new Curriculum__c();
    saved = false;
}

public PageReference save() {
    try {
        // Validazione effettuata qui perchè il required sull'inputCheckbox non è utilizzabile
        if (!privacy) {
            ApexPages.Message reqMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Autorizzare il trattamento dei dati personali');
            ApexPages.addMessage(reqMsg);
            return null;
        }

        // Inserisce il record
        insert(curriculum);
        // Inserisce l'allegato
        if (resume != null) {
            Attachment attach = new Attachment();
            attach.Body = resume;
            attach.Name = fileName;
            attach.ContentType= contentType;
            attach.ParentId = curriculum.id;                
            try {
                insert(attach);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // TODO fare il roolback dell'inserimento del curriculum?

                ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
                return null;
            }                    
        }

        //Papagni 03/09/2013 - update curriculum per fare scattare il trigger di after che invia la mail
        update curriculum;

        saved = true;

    } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);  
    }
    return null;   

}
```

}

Comment: Did you try making `resume` [transient](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm) to keep it out of the view state? i.e. `public Transient Blob resume {get; set;}`

Comment: fine, it works!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [View State](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State) will most likely be caused by this tag because `resume` could be a rather large `Blob`.

```
    <apex:inputFile id="resume" fileName="{!fileName}" contentType="{!contentType}" value="{!resume}" size="45"/>
```

You don't need to store `resume` in the View State. You can use the [Transient Keyword](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm) to make sure its not included in the View State. If you change your declaration of `resume` to what is shown below then it should stop your issue:

```
public Transient Blob resume {get; set;}
```

From sfdcfox's [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/35005/view-state-and-transient):

> Transient variables are not stored in the view state, but can be
>   regenerated by the post back if bound to an input element. In general,
>   you only need to use the view state for elements not bound to an input
>   element and need to maintain state between post backs.

Comment: Have look into the same issue I am facing many times - 
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70483/file-attachment-upload-maximum-file-size-limit-exceeded-135mb

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to set `resume = null;`, empty fields are not going in viewstate.

Comment: @martin well, I had the same issue as asker, and this solution worked for me. So this is possible way of avoiding asker's issue.

Comment: My apologies, I misread your answer.